# Difference in @Resource and @Autowired

Tags: spring

I don't understand why the following line gives an error when i annotate it with @Resource, I don't get this error when i write @Autowired.

```
@Resource(name = "systemConfigService")
private SystemConfigService systemConfigService;
```

It tells , unable to resolve bean systemConfigService

SystemConfigService is an interface.

Comment: Show your configuration for bean of systemConfigService

Comment: What happens if you annotate it with `@Autowired(required = true)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Autowired in combination with @Qualifier also autowires by name. The main difference is is that @Autowired is a spring annotation whereas @Resource is specified by the JSR-250. So the latter is part of normal java where as @Autowired is only available by spring.

> if you intend to express annotation-driven injection by name, do not
>   primarily use @Autowired - even if is technically capable of referring
>   to a bean name through @Qualifier values. Instead, prefer the JSR-250
>   @Resource annotation which is semantically defined to identify a
>   specific target component by its unique name, with the declared type
>   being irrelevant for the matching process.
>
> As a specific consequence of this semantic difference, beans which are
>   themselves defined as a collection or map type cannot be injected via
>   @Autowired since type matching is not properly applicable to them. Use
>   @Resource for such beans, referring to the specific collection/map
>   bean by unique name.

**Note:** In contrast to @Autowired which is applicable to fields, constructors and multi-argument methods (allowing for narrowing through qualifier annotations at the parameter level), @Resource is only supported for fields and bean property setter methods with a single argument. As a consequence, stick with qualifiers if your injection target is a constructor or a multi-argument method.